# How can I obtain null and residual deviance/degrees of freedom for assessing model significance?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to determine model significance using:

```
1-pchisq(null deviance-residual deviance, null df- residual df)
```

I have 5 models:

- Four models were estimated with GLMs, which gave me null and residual DFs in the summary.
- The fifth model was estimated with the `lmer` function because of the nested structure of my data. This does not give me degrees of freedom for null or residuals.

How do I get my null and residual deviances and degrees of freedoms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The concept of numbers of parameters and hence df in the lmer model is kind of fuzzy. Don't bother with it, and use AICc; you stand on firmer theoretical ground: http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~anderson/PDF_files/TESTING.pdf

Comment: The link isn't working for me.